# Custom title for each item using itemize package

Tags: formatting, lists

I want to create a list in which each item has its own title. For instance,

First item:   This is the first item
              with a custom title

Different title: the second item has a different
                 one

Alternative title: This is my 
                  third item

etc...

How can I produce such list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no `itemize` package, as far as I know. Are you looking for the `description` environment.

Comment: anything that might work :) I am not very familiar wit list packages (itemize, enumerate, description, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very basic, not much can be done here. Otherwise customize the `itemize` list with `enumitem` package to provide other typesetting facilities.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}

\item Foo

We have something to say here

\item Foobar

We have to say something differently here

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I do it by using `enumitem` package?

Comment: @Yorgos: The problem is: You're not providing any assistance within your question. There is no indication what you want to achieve

Comment: i know that my question it's a bit confusing, but `description` packages it's ok